# If two analytical real-valued functions agree (alongside all their derivatives) on an open interval, then they are equal.

Tags: real-analysis

If I have two analytical functions $f,g: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (where $I$ is an open interval) and I know that there is a point $a \in I$ where $f(a) = g(a)$, $f'(a) = g'(a)$, $f''(a) = g''(a)$, and so on and so on, then I wanna prove that $f(x) = g(x)$ for every $x \in I$. I know that this implies there is gonna be an open interval where $f$ and $g$ and all of their derivatives will agree, but I'm stuck after that. I feel like I should know how to do this... Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend taking a look at the Wikipedia page for the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) of complex analysis.

To expand a bit on the argument there: Consider the set $A$ of points in $I$ where $f$ and $g$ agree.

Since $f-g$ is continuous and $A = (f-g)^{-1}(\{0\})$, $A$ must be closed in $I$ as it's the preimage a closed set.

Since $f$ and $g$ are analytic we must have that $A = \{x \in I \mid f^{(k)}(x) = g^{(k)}(x)$ for all $k\geq 0\}$.

Now consider a $c \in A$. Because $f$ and $g$ are analytic we have positive radius of convergence of their Taylor series around $c$ and we get that $\{x \in I \mid |x-c| < r\} \subset A$ for some $r > 0$ showing that every point of $A$ is an interior point, i.e. $A$ is open in $I$.

Now we have that $A$ is a non-empty (because $a \in A$) [clopen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set) subset of $I$, so it must be all of $I$.

Comment: I'm trying, but it's got a lot of stuff I don't know...

Comment: Okay, okay. I think there's only one part where I can't follow: why is it that $A = \{x \in I \mid f^{(k)}(x) = g^{(k)}(x)$ for all $k\geq 0\}$? Why is it that if two analytic functions agree on a single point, then all of their derivatives at that point must also agree?

Comment: Well, I couldn't prove what I just asked you, but if I suppose that $A = \{x \in I \mid f^{(k)}(x) = g^{(k)}(x)$ for all $k\geq 0\}$ I can easily prove that A is a clopen subset of I, and therefore I! Thanks for the help :)