# Analytical functions equal at a point implies all derivatives are also equal at that point?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analyticity

There is this problem that goes as follows:

---

If I have two analytical functions $f,g:I→R$
(where $I$ is an open interval), and I know that there is a point $a∈I$ 
 where $f(a)=g(a)$ and also $f^{(k)}(a)=g^{(k)}(a), \enspace \forall k \in \mathbb{R}$ where $k$ is denoting the degree of the derivative. Then show that$f(x)=g(x) \enspace \forall x\in I$

---

I know the standard approach to solve this, which is given [at this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145789/if-two-analytical-real-valued-functions-agree-alongside-all-their-derivatives).

**My question is:** In the way the questions is presented to me in my book, it is **given** that we also have $f^{(k)}(a)=g^{(k)}(a)$. But is this simply a consequence to the fact that $f \& g$ are both analytical and equal at the point $a \in I$ ?? If so, haw can I show this?

Comment: For *analytical* functions it suffices that their derivatives of all orders agree at $a$. That's because they are represented by Taylor series, and those are uniquely determined by those derivatives. This is *not sufficient* for $C^{\infty}$-functions. The textbook example being $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$, both with vanishing derivatives of all orders at $a=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not a consequence. Take $f,g\colon\mathbb R\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=0$ and by $g(x)=x$. Then you have $f(0)=g(0)$, but $0=f'(0)\neq g'(0)=1$.

Comment: The way I read it, the OP is asking whether ot not the assertion $(\forall k\in\mathbb N):f^{(k)}(0)=g^{(k)}(0)$ is a consequence of $f(0)=g(0)$, assuming that $f$ and $g$ are analytical.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the case. Doesn't make any sense to me, but... :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Well, I also thought that it was a strange question…